# Comparing certain line of text file with input

Tags: python

I need code which compares the input to line 2 of a text file. I have started writing the code but it is not working, I now it is wrong on the 3rd line but don't know what to do.

```
Name = input("Enter name: ")
with open("numbers") as MyFile:
      if line 2 == Name:
         print ("correct")
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `readlines` and get second line :

```
Name = input("Enter name: ")
with open("numbers") as MyFile:
    line2 = MyFile.readlines()[1]
    print(Name, line2)
```

Answer (score 1):

I will try to provide a little more explanation. You must define your basic variables. One can see that line 2, is both not a variable at all because it has a space, and is not ever declared!

```
name = input("Enter name: ")
with open("numbers") as f:
    lines = f.readlines() # a list of all the lines
    if lines[1] == name: # the second line (0 indexing)
         print ("correct")
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define 'line 2'.  Try:

```
name = input("Enter name: ")
with open("numbers") as MyFile:
    lines = MyFile.readlines()
    if lines[1] == name:
         print ("correct")
```